# Can I implement tab autocomplete in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, auto-completion

I have a script that, when a user enters a file name in a directory, performs automatic tagging operations on that file (mp3 tagging).

My problem: It gets really tedious typing in the exact file name of every song I want to tag, and I was wondering if it is possible to implement tab autocompletion when I input the name of a file.

The beginning of my script:

## Input file name and locate file

```
echo  "Enter name of file to be tagged"
read -e FileName
FileFindTest=$(find ~/Downloads/"$FileName")
echo "$FileFindTest"
```

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly (for me), `read` does simple file / folder autocomplete with the `-e` option.

To use it in your example (I've noted my changes)

```bash
echo  "Enter name of file to be tagged:"

cd ~/Downloads      ## cd to Downloads folder for autocomplete

read -e FileName

FileFindTest="$(find ~/Downloads/"$FileName")"  ## quoted 

echo "$FileFindTest"
```

In this case, when asking for input it will autocomplete files/folder in your Downloads folder.

---

Example, suppose you have the following files in your Downloads folder:

```
~/Downloads
│
├───Pop/
│   └───PopSong.mp3
├───Song1.mp3
└───Song5.mp3
```

Then when you will have the following results (pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> when `<TAB>` is shown)

```
P<TAB>
Pop/

S<TAB>
Song1.mp3 Song5.mp3

PopSong.mp3<TAB>
# (nothing found here, as it's searching in Downloads/ only not Pop/)

Pop/P<TAB>
PopSong.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would benefit from reading on [How to create script with auto-complete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete)

If the `cd` workaround doesn't cut it for you, you could try [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/345150) an replace the static values with a listing.
Or you can go head on into [Programmable Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) from Bash Manual.